# How to make a view move as part of RecyclerView using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, nestedscrollview

I am learning Android CoordinatorLayout/RecyclerView/Behavior/Nested scroll stuff. I found the APIs are not very straight forward. Thus I did a little experiment but found the behaviors of views inside CoordinatorLayout do not come out as expected.

Here is what I want to do: I want to have a CoordinatoryLayout as the parent container. Inside it, there is a RecyclerView as its child. Also as its child, there is another View that is in red color. I want the red view to move as the RecyclerView scrolls. I want the movement of the two views so synchronized that it seems that the red view is part of the RecyclerView.

Note: I am aware that to achieve what I just said, there is much more simpler ways. But I just want to do it with CoordinatorLayout and Behavior class so that I can learn how they work.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="io.github.seemuch.coordinatorlayoutexperiment.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/red_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my behavior class:

```
package io.github.seemuch.coordinatorlayoutexperiment;

import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;


public class MyBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {
    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View toolbar, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof RecyclerView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                             View child,
                             View directTargetChild,
                             View target,
                             int nestedScrollAxes) {

        int vertical = (nestedScrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
        int horizontal = (nestedScrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_HORIZONTAL);

        return (vertical != 0 && horizontal == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll (CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                        View child,
                        View target,
                        int dx,
                        int dy,
                        int[] consumed) {

        float currY = child.getY();
        if (currY <= 0 && dy >= 0) {
        return;
        }
        child.setY(currY - dy);
    }

}
```

As you can see in the onNestedPreScroll method, I want the child, which is the red_view, move as much as the view it depends on, which is the RecyclerView.

What actually happened was this: if you scroll the RecyclerView with very big movement, the red view does move with it, as expected; but if you move very little, the red_view moves much faster than the RecyclerView.

Here is a link to the screen record video: https://youtu.be/zK4g61F2aa0
And here is the Github repo of the project, incase you want to download it and run it yourself: https://github.com/seemuch/CoordinatorLayoutExperiment

So, anybody knows what happened?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: Do not override onNestedPreScroll, instead, override onNestedScroll(). Simple as that.
It does not handle fling, though. Flings need to be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue doing something pretty simple. First I defined the `RecyclerView` not scrollable (we still have the touch for each row) and then I put a `ScrollView` in the layout.

Here some code:

**layout.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="729dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.505" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.089" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val adapter = PersonAdapter { /*handle touch*/ }
            val manager = CustomGridLayoutManager(this)
            manager.setScrollEnabled(false)
            recycler.layoutManager = manager
            recycler.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
```

**CustomGridLayoutManager.kt**

```
class CustomGridLayoutManager(context: Context?) :
    LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    private var isScrollEnabled = true
    fun setScrollEnabled(flag: Boolean) {
        isScrollEnabled = flag
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean { 
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically()
    }
}
```

**PersonAdapter.kt**

```
class PersonAdapter(val onItemClick : (Int) -> (Unit))
: RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private val personList = arrayOf("marco", "anna", "gianna", "giulia", "alice", "sini", "marco", "anna", "gianna",
    "giulia", "alice", "sini", "marco", "anna", "gianna", "giulia", "alice", "sini", "marco", "anna", "gianna", "giulia", "alice", "sini")

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return personList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val element = personList[position]

    holder.text.text = element

    holder.text.setOnClickListener {
        onItemClick(position)
    }

    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val text = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textRow)
    }
}
```